# How can I turn my Galaxy Tab 7" into a Kindle Fire?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, amazon-kindle-fire

I got a Galaxy Tab from work and I don't use it that much, but the screen size and specs look pretty similar to the new Kindle Fire.  I know next to nothing about how things work under the covers but I know that there is a large hacker/modding community within Android.  So is it even feasible to attempt such a thing?  If not, why, in layman's terms please :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless Amazon releases their Kindle Fire source code, there won't be a way to mod a different Android tablet to be a faux Fire. I seriously doubt that will happen

That's not to say that someone won't be able to put together some combination of mods and apps that might approximate some of the Fire's functionality, but that's a pretty daunting task, if Amazon's proprietary changes don't make it completely impossible.

***Update***: How about that? Amazon actually *did* release the Kindle Fire source code. http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/technology/2011/11/amazon-releases-kindle-fire-source-code.html

***Update 2***: It seems that someone's got something very close. [Android Spin has details](http://androidspin.com/2011/11/22/can-you-turn-a-galaxy-tab-into-a-kindle-fire-someone-sure-did/).